# Load SSL configuration via JVM arguments relative path

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, thin-client

Trying to load sas.client.props file present in classpath

[image]

I have configuration inside resource/conf directory. I would like to send this file as argument to my program via JVM arguments -D.

This works:

```
-Dcom.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL=file:E:\inteliJworkspace\project1\target\classes\conf\ssl.client.props
```

File exists in resource dir: 
    System.out.println(new Test().getClass().getResource("/conf/sas.client.props"));

But how can I send this /conf/sas.client.props from compiled classes directory relative path via JVM arguments?

This is not working:

```
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=conf\sas.client.props
```

JSAS0629E: [loadPropertiesFile] MalformedURLException reading com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/conf\sas.client.props.  Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: conf\sas.client.props
JSAS1478W: Security cannot be enabled because the ConfigURL property cannot be processed!

This is not working:

```
-Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=\conf\sas.client.props
```

JSAS0629E: [loadPropertiesFile] MalformedURLException reading com.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL=file:/conf\sas.client.props.  Exception: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: \conf\sas.client.props
JSAS1478W: Security cannot be enabled because the ConfigURL property cannot be processed!

I tried every option I could remember, but couldn't get it working!

Comment: I believe they have to be set at the JVM Argument level. So it's outside the application running.

Answer (score 0):

Windows: -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL="file:C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppClient\properties\sas.client.props"

AIX: -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL="file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppClient/properties/sas.client.props"

Other UNIX: -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.ConfigURL="file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppClient/properties/sas.client.props"

Thank,
Ut Le

Comment: You are using fix-ed installed paths, I'm looking for way to load this from my local jar ( relative path)